# Error after bind JQGgrid to bind other asp.net control

Tags: c#, asp.net, jqgrid-asp.net

I have a problem when I want to bind a control after binding my Jqgrid component

**ASP.NET :**

```
<%--Liste des sujets--%>
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <trirand:JQGrid runat="server" ID="JQGChoixSujets" Height="340"
```

**C#**

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                if (JQGChoixSujets.AjaxCallBackMode == AjaxCallBackMode.RequestData || JQGChoixSujets.AjaxCallBackMode == AjaxCallBackMode.Search)
                {
                    BindGridView();
                }
            }

        }
```

....

```
private void BindGridView()
    {
        try
        {
            _bsChoixSujet = new BSChoixSujet();
            _lstBEChoixSujet = _bsChoixSujet.GetChoixSujets(_contact.IdCrm, EnumChoixSujetPrefix.SE);

            if (_lstBEChoixSujet != null && _lstBEChoixSujet.Count > 0)
            {
                // Mise à plat
                var result = from choix in _lstBEChoixSujet
                             select new
                             {
                                 UpDown = String.Empty,
                                 ....

                             };

                JQGChoixSujets.DataSource = result;
                JQGChoixSujets.DataBind();


                // Nombre de choix de sujets total
                hdfNumberRows.Value = _lstBEChoixSujet.Count().ToString();

                // Nombre de choix de sujets proposés
                hdfMemoireNbrPropositionsRealises.Value = _lstBEChoixSujet.Where(x => x.ThemeSujet.Sujet.Code.StartsWith(Constantes.CONST_PREFIX_CODE_SUJET_ETUDIANT)).Count().ToString();


            }
        }
```

So the problem, My JQGrid is bound but not my hiddenfield hdfNumberRows & hdfMemoireNbrPropositionsRealises.

If I bind these controls out the AjaxCallBackMode.RequestData, my hiddenfield are bound without error, but I need to bind them inside the AjaxCallBackMode.RequestData.

Comment: If those are runat=server hidden inputs, what are they going to generate as the response stream to this ajax call and how is that going to be propagated into the client DOM by the jqGrid callback?

Comment: I want to get the value of those hidden inputs in the loadcomplete function of my jqgrid <ClientSideEvents LoadComplete="loadComplete" />

Comment: Right, and if you take a look at your response stream, are the values of those fields anywhere in the JSON (or XML, or whichever encoding that particular combination of jqGrid returns) coming back from the server? A custom webmethod may do more like what you're attempting....